# Psexec is not opening chrome browser on the remote machine

Tags: c#, psexec

I have to call an application in a remote machine and for that I am using **Psexec** tool.

When I run the below command in my local computer, it runs the **ConsoleTest.exe** on the remote machine.

> psexec \\remote -u Administrator -p MyPassword 
>   C:\Practice\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest\bin\Debug\ConsoleTest.exe

My ConsoleTest application code is something like below and the Psexec is unable to open the chrome browser with the given url. Is it possible to open the Browser in the remote machine with Psexec tool?
Am I missing any configurations? Thank you so much in advance.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Psexec invoked!");
            Process.Start("chrome.exe", "microsoft.com");
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Practice\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest\bin\Debug\log.txt", 
                "Completed at : " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

Comment: If you don't run psexec with the `-i` flag, the process doesn't have access to interact with the user, and can't display a GUI. Did you check Task Manager to verify `chrome.exe` wasn't running as a background process?